# python - getting error (urllib2.URLError) using pandas model

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am doing a project which requires having stocks data (currant and past). I am planning to show the data with a nice Gui engine which will have some nice features.

I have read on the pandas model and decided to use it, it seemed to support what I need. But I just have a little problem - it does not work. I did exactly what I read and saw. To them it work, but not for me! Here is what I have tried: (pandas installed from pip (pip install pandas))

```
import datetime
import pandas.io.data as data

start = datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1)
apple = data.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start, end)
```

when I do this an error pops out :
**urllib2.URLError: urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed**

And when I tried replacing 'yahoo' with 'google' it succeeded, but returned None.

I have tried this code from several devices and all the same result (I am using python 2.7)

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few issues in the code:
pandas.io is not supported; use pandas_datareader instead

but I think the main issue is that your start_date > end_date here
switching them around fixed the issue

Comment: Same happens when I switch the dates. About the pandas_datareader, it does not finds it...

Comment: execute "pip install pandas_datareader" from command line before trying to import it

Comment: I have installed now pandas_datareader from pip, it works with it!!! thanks very much :)